# A compact convex set on a Hilbert space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

If i let $x\in H$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space, and let $K$ be a compact convex  set

Why there exists $a\in K$ such that $$||x-a||=\inf_{k\in K} ||x-k||$$

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The function $f:K\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(k)=||x-k||$ for $k\in K$ is continuous and attains a minimum over a compact subset. The uniqueness of $a$ is assured by the convexity.

Comment: How we prove the uniqueness please ?

Comment: @Saha Abishanka

Answer (score 0):

For uniqueness, let $k_1,k_2\in K$ be two distinct points of minimal distance from $a$. Then their midpoint $(k_1+k_2)/2$ is of smaller distance from $a$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: How to see that $<k_1-k_2, x-\frac{k_1+k_2}{2}>=0$ ?please

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I find it in a pdf they calculate this after they deduce that k_1=k_2 I don't understand how

Comment: Can you send the pdf?

Comment: How i can do this ? the pdf is writting in French !

Comment: I see... I can try to read it but I will probably not understand. In any case, I think chilangoincomprendido's answer solves the matter, right?

Comment: that is the answer: if $b\in K$ such that $||x-b||=\inf_{k\in K}=||x-a||$ then $<a-b,x-\frac{a+b}{2}>=0$ and then $-||x-\frac{a+b}{2}||^2+||x-a||^2=||\frac{a-b}{2}||^2.$ but $\frac{a-b}{2}\in K$ by convexity of K and then $||\frac{a-b}{2}||^2\leq ||x-a||^2-||x-\frac{a+b}{2}||^2\leq 0.$ So $a=b$ I don't understand this answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69665/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-cronus).

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Cronus' answer: uniqueness follows from convexity and the parallelogram identity:

$\left \| k_1+k_2-2a \right \|^{2}+\left \| k_1-k_2 \right \|^{2}=2\left \| k_1-a \right \|^{2}+2\left \| k_2-a \right \|^{2}\Rightarrow $

$\left \| \frac{ k_1+k_2}{2}-a \right \|^{2}=d^{2}(x,K)-\frac{1}{4}\left \| k_1-k_2 \right \|^2$

from which we infer that unless $k_1=k_2$, the distance to $a$ of $\frac{ k_1+k_2}{2}$ is less than the minimum distance, which is a contradiction.

Comment: i don't understand how you find that $k_1=k_2$